# Pass argument of main directly to write function

Tags: c, sizeof, c-strings, strlen

I have C program which already takes an argument, stores it into a buffer and then passes it to a write function:

```
main(int argc, char** argv) {

    ...

    char buff[1000];
    strcpy(buff, argv[1]);

    write(server_socket, buff, sizeof(buff));     

    ...

    return 0;
}
```

If I execute my code: `./testCode "equinox`", `equinox` will be stored in buffer and then buffer will be passed to the `write()` function. Everything would work as expected in this case.

Is there a way of skipping the part in which I store the argument in a buffer and then pass it to write()?

Is it correct if I do something like:

```
write(server_socket, argv[1], sizeof(argv[1]));
```

I am not even sure whether this would work as expected.

Comment: `argv` is a pointer to a pointer to `char`, and can be seen as an array of *pointers*. The size of a pointer is the size of the *pointer itself*, not what it might point to. To get the length of a null-terminated string use [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen).

Comment: The correct answer here depends on what the server expects.  What you're doing right now is correct if and only if the server expects to read exactly 1000 bytes of data from the socket, the first few bytes of which are a C-string, and the remainder will be ignored.  If the protocol is different, the correct answer is different.  Please tell us what the server expects.

Comment: You may want to consider this call: `write(server_socket, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));`

Comment: I don't think the original code is correct either. You're leaking random parts of your stack memory after the argument

Comment: regarding: `strcpy(buff, argv[1])` This very risky because there is no checking that the string pointed to by `argv[1]` is less than 1000 bytes long.  Suggest: `strncpy(buff, argv[1], sizeof( buff )-1)`

Comment: regarding: `write(server_socket, buff, sizeof(buff));`  This will write 1000 bytes, starting at the address contained in `argv[1]`  This (probably) is accessing memory way beyond the end of the string pointed to by `argv[1]`.  Suggest:  `write(server_socket, buff, strlen(buff));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This statement

```
write(server_socket, buff, sizeof(buff));
```

and this statement

```
write(server_socket, argv[1], sizeof(argv[1]));
```

are both incorrect because they do not correctly specify the number of bytes that are written.

In the first case the size of the string can be less than the size of buff. In the second case there is used the size of a pointer that is equal to 4 or 8 bytes.

What you need is

```
write(server_socket, argv[1], strlen( argv[1] ) );
```

or

```
write(server_socket, buff, strlen(buff));
```

Comment: This answer may or may not be correct depending on the protocol spoken by the server. We don't have enough information from OP to know.

Comment: @zwol The function write does not depend on a protocol. It sends n bytes of characters.

Comment: Yes, but whether it is _correct_ to send `strlen(argv[1])` bytes of characters, or `sizeof(buff)` bytes of characters, or what, depends on the protocol spoken by the server.

Comment: It's possible, even likely, that the proper answer to this question is something like "You need to copy the string into a buffer, or else use `writev` instead of `write`, because you need to put 'GET /' in front of the string and ' HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: something.example\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n' after it."

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, it would work, but with a slight modification:

```
write(server_socket, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
```

Since `argv[1]` is a pointer to a `char` array, the `sizeof` operator would return the size of a pointer in your machine (which would be 8, if you're on a 64-bit machine). Instead, you should use `strlen` to get the number of bytes to write.

Comment: This answer may or may not be correct depending on the protocol spoken by the server.  We don't have enough information from OP to know.

Comment: @zwol How so? I don't think the `write` function depends on a protocol.

Comment: Yes, but whether it is _correct_ to send `strlen(argv[1])` bytes of characters, or `sizeof(buff)` bytes of characters, or what, depends on the protocol spoken by the server.